# Is Risk Adjusted CAGR formula from Investopedia correct?

Tags: cagr

https://www.investopedia.com/investing/compound-annual-growth-rate-what-you-should-know/

"A simple method for calculating a risk-adjusted CAGR is to **multiply the CAGR by one minus the standard deviation. If the standard deviation (risk) is zero, the risk-adjusted CAGR is unaffected. The larger the standard deviation, the lower the risk-adjusted CAGR.**"

I have not seen this used widely as Sharpe/Sortino Ratio to measure risk adjisted returns hence the question. I assume the standard deviation has to be annualized.

Comment: Same question also posted here https://www.bogleheads.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=6765166

Comment: This seems like nonsense since $g$ is equal to $\mu$ adjusted for risk https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/49008/mathematical-proof-of-g-mu-frac-sigma22-relationship-between-cagr-a Why do we need to make a second adjustment for risk? And why would it be linear?